# WebBrowser - How to type into that textbox 2

Tags: .net, vb.net

As title I'm trying to solve a very similar problem I had in the past.
I'm unable to write into a textbox and I don't understand why.
Fields in which I'm trying to type are special fields (password), **[Old Password, New Password, Confirm Password]** so I don't know if this could be the reason I'm able to handle any other field or element in this ACP, except the password ones.
The HTML code:

```html
<div id="panel-1267-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 156px; width: 445px;">
   <div id="panel-1267-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;">
      <table class="undefined align-left x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-password x-box-item -default x-vbox-form-item" style="width: 440px; height: 32px; table-layout: fixed; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1255">
         <tbody>
            <tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1255-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row">
               <td role="presentation" id="textfield-1255-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="185" class="x-field-label-cell"><label id="textfield-1255-labelEl" for="textfield-1255-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label textlabel x-unselectable textlabel-left cuttitle" style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on" title=""><span t="sys.OldPwd" id="ext-gen1674">Old Password</span></label></td>
               <td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1255-bodyEl" colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><input id="textfield-1255-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1255-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" style="margin: 0px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 47px; height: 99px; width: 445px;" id="ext-comp-1256">
         <div id="ext-comp-1256-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 99px;">
            <div id="ext-comp-1256-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 99px; width: 445px;">
               <div id="ext-comp-1256-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;">
                  <div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" id="panel-1262" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 99px; width: 445px;">
                     <div id="panel-1262-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 99px;">
                        <div id="panel-1262-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="width: 445px; height: 99px;">
                           <div id="panel-1262-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;">
                              <div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" style="width: 445px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 99px;" id="panel-1263">
                                 <div id="panel-1263-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="width: 445px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 99px;">
                                    <div id="panel-1263-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 99px; width: 445px;">
                                       <div id="panel-1263-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;">
                                          <div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" id="panel-1264" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 42px; width: 445px;">
                                             <div id="panel-1264-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 42px;">
                                                <span id="panel-1264-outerCt" style="display:table;">
                                                   <div id="panel-1264-innerCt" style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; display: table-cell;" class="">
                                                      <table class="undefined align-left x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-password -default x-autocontainer-form-item" style="width: 440px; height: 32px; table-layout: fixed;" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1260">
                                                         <tbody>
                                                            <tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1260-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row">
                                                               <td role="presentation" id="textfield-1260-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="185" class="x-field-label-cell"><label id="textfield-1260-labelEl" for="textfield-1260-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label textlabel x-unselectable textlabel-left cuttitle" style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on" title=""><span t="sys.NewPwd" id="ext-gen1675">New Password</span></label></td>
                                                               <td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1260-bodyEl" colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><input id="textfield-1260-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1260-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                      <div class="x-panel showLevel x-panel-default" style="width: 260px; height: 5px;" id="panel-1265">
                                                         <div id="panel-1265-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="width: 260px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 5px;">
                                                            <span id="panel-1265-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
                                                               <div id="panel-1265-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class="">
                                                                  <div class="x-panel x-panel-default" id="pwdlevel" style="height: 5px;">
                                                                     <div id="pwdlevel-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 260px; height: 5px;">
                                                                        <div id="pwdlevel-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="width: 260px; height: 5px;">
                                                                           <div id="pwdlevel-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 260px;">
                                                                              <div class=" pwd_defaultCls x-box-item -default" style="height: 5px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 83px;" id="panel-1257">
                                                                                 <div id="panel-1257-body" class="-body -body-default -body-default" style="height: 5px; width: 83px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                                                                                    <span id="panel-1257-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;">
                                                                                       <div id="panel-1257-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div>
                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                 </div>
                                                                              </div>
                                                                              <div class=" pwd_defaultCls x-box-item -default" style="height: 5px; right: auto; left: 86px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 84px;" id="panel-1258">
                                                                                 <div id="panel-1258-body" class="-body -body-default -body-default" style="height: 5px; width: 84px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                                                                                    <span id="panel-1258-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;">
                                                                                       <div id="panel-1258-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div>
                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                 </div>
                                                                              </div>
                                                                              <div class=" pwd_defaultCls x-box-item -default" style="height: 5px; right: auto; left: 173px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 84px;" id="panel-1259">
                                                                                 <div id="panel-1259-body" class="-body -body-default -body-default" style="height: 5px; width: 84px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                                                                                    <span id="panel-1259-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;">
                                                                                       <div id="panel-1259-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div>
                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                 </div>
                                                                              </div>
                                                                           </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                  </div>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </span>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </span>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <table class="undefined align-left x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-password x-box-item -default x-vbox-form-item" style="width: 440px; height: 32px; table-layout: fixed; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 52px; margin: 0px;" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1261">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1261-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row">
                                                   <td role="presentation" id="textfield-1261-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="185" class="x-field-label-cell"><label id="textfield-1261-labelEl" for="textfield-1261-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label textlabel x-unselectable textlabel-left cuttitle" style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on" title=""><span t="sys.Pwdconfirm" id="ext-gen1676">Confirm Password</span></label></td>
                                                   <td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1261-bodyEl" colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><input id="textfield-1261-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1261-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("textfield-1091-inputEl") Then
        Element.SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")
        Return
    End If
Next
```

and:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If Element.Id.Contains("textfield-1091-inputEl") Then
        Element.SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")
        Return
    End If
Next
```

and:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textfield-1091-inputEl").SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")
```

Without results.

Comment: Instead of .SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt") try Browser1.Document.GetElementById("textfield-1091-inputEl").innerHTML='texttttt'

Comment: @Miguel I tried but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You get a `NullReferenceException` because there's nothing in the HTML with that ID (or Text). As suggested, use `GetElementById()` passing an **existing** ID. -- For example you have an INPUT element defined as `<input id="textfield-1255-inputEl" type="password" .../>` and two more, with different IDs. -- You can also get all the `INPUT` elements and set a value using their sequence.

Comment: I couldn't find the Id "textfield-1091-inputEl" in your HTML, maybe the problem is there. But i found the Id "textfield-1255-inputEl" (old password) try with with this Id just to see is something is shown in this textbox.